# Focusing adverb 'just'

Tags: adverb-placement

To express only the thing I think is I fly in the air, is 'I think just that I fly in the air' grammatically correct? I wonder focusing adverbs can focus on not only phrases but clauses!

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Focusing-Adverbs.htm

Comment: What does this sentence mean? It think it's correct but strange if what you mean is the only thing you think is that you are flying.

Comment: I agree with EB.  Your sentence is equivalent to, "The only thing I think is that I fly in the air".   It seems very unlikely that this is the only thing that you think - surely you sometimes think other things. Please can you explain in different words, what you wish your sentence to mean.

Comment: Yes, 'The only thing I think is that I fly in the air' is what I'm trying to say.